# Cannot login to website using requests module (Python version 3.5.1)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, csrf

I am trying to access a website to scrape some information, however I am having trouble posting login information through Python. Here is my code so far:

```
import requests

c = requests.Session()
url = 'https://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/login/login.html'
USERNAME = 'user'
PASSWORD = 'pass'

c.get(url)
csrftoken = c.cookies['csrftoken']
login_data = dict(j_username=USERNAME, j_password=PASSWORD,           
csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken, next='/')
c.post(url, data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=url))
page = c.get('http://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/home/index.html')
print(page.content)
```

**Here is the form data from the post login page:**

j_username:user
j_password:pass
OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:8N0Z-TND5-NV71-C4N4-43BK-B13S-A1MO-NZQC
OWASP_CSRFTOKEN:8N0Z-TND5-NV71-C4N4-43BK-B13S-A1MO-NZQC

**Here is the error I receive**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/10023539/Desktop/pyscripts/webscraper ex.py", line 9, in <module>
    csrftoken = c.cookies['csrftoken']
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 293, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 351, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"
```

I believe the issue has something to do with the 'OWASP_CSRFTOKEN' label? I haven't found any solutions for this specific CSRF name anywhere online. I've also tried removing the c.cookies method and manually typing in the CSRF code into the csrfmiddlewaretoken argument. I've also tried changing the referal URL around, still getting the same error.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you seeing the form data? In particular `csrfmiddlewaretoken`?

Comment: I took the form data from the page after the log in. I used 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' because I saw that as an example in the documentations. Am I supposed to be using something different? Also, if you need more information from the headers or anything, please let me know I'd be happy to post.

Comment: Yes, the name in the actual form data, open developer tools and you will see you are also posting to the incorrect url, it is `https://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/j_spring_security_check` ans `OWASP_CSRFTOKEN` is the name for the csrf token

Comment: Yup, that did the trick :). I was posting the wrong URL, and and I had to change the form data to "OWASP_CSRFTOKEN". Thank you Padraic!

Comment: No worries, the network tab under  firebug or developer tools is your friend when it comes to mimicking requests

Answer (score 0):

First of all you catch `KeyError` exception, this mean that `cookies` dictionary have no key `csrftoken`.

So you need explore your response for find right CSRF token cookie name.
For example you can print all cookies:

```
for key in c.cookies.keys():
    print('%s: %s' % (key, c.cookies[key]))
```

UPD: Actually your response have no CSRF cookie.
you need look token in your `c.text` with `pyquery`

```
<input type="hidden" name="OWASP_CSRFTOKEN" class="csrfClass" value="X48L-NEYI-CG18-SJOD-VDW9-FGEB-7WIT-88P4">
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please be a little more specific? What exactly am I looking for in the response? Also, are there other ways to view my response? I'm still getting errors when putting this code in.

Comment: That html is dynamically generated so you won't be getting that in the source returned