# Error while fetching csrftoken

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm getting error while i'm trying to fetch the csrftoken.
I tried changing the token name from csrftoken to csrf but i'm still getting the error.

```
import requests
url='myurl'
Username='username'
Password='password'

requests.Session().get(url)

csrftoken= requests.Session().cookies['csrftoken']
logindata=dict(csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken,username=
Username,password=Password)

requests.Session().post(url,data=logindata,headers={'referer' :'homepage'})

page=requests.session().get('2nd url')
print page.content
```

The error is :-

> File
>   "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
>   es\requests\cookies.py", line 329, in __getitem__return
>   self._find_no_duplicates(name)'
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packa
>   es\requests\cookies.py", line 400, in _find_no_duplicates raise
>   KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
>   eyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"'

Comment: and what about *domain=None, path=None*.. did you followup on the error message and provided required info? Moidfy your question such that requested response info is in it. Then your question is pretty much complete and shot in to the world-wide-web waiting for help responses ;-)

Comment: Thanx for replying but actually i'm new to python so i'm unable to actually detect the error i'm searching the web but not able to find why i'm getting the erorr. And  i found out other library which is mechanicalsoup. will be trying  to login with it  and will update if i'm able to login.

Comment: Hint... google or here at SO + search function + *eyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"'* = possible solution  [>> here <<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816858/cannot-login-to-website-using-requests-module-python-version-3-5-1). Or [here](https://www.google.nl/search?q=python+eyError%3A+%22name%3D%27csrftoken%27%2C+domain%3DNone%2C+path%3DNone%22%27&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=L6aMWuKdLpDA8gec2JSAAQ).

Comment: Thanx for the help.i'll se if i can get it

Comment: actually i had checked the webpage html code there were no hidden element.and also can you pls tell me how can i find the cookie name.coz is it that i'm putting the cookie name wrong and hence getting the error

Comment: Sorry but I've never worked with cookies and python-requests like this. But I know how to search... check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567507/passing-csrftoken-with-python-requests) and read the comments from Martijn Pieters about cookies, servers in debug mode, etc.

Comment: ok i'll see.....

Comment: but in my case i'm not able to execute the step in which the referer is given i'm getting the error before that step. which is this line "csrftoken= requests.Session().cookies['csrftoken']"

Comment: can you pls help me finding the csrf token name...?. coz i have searched the whole html code but was not able to find it

Answer (score 0):

This code evades the `Session` part of `requests` version with capital "S". Try to see if this works for you:

```
import requests

url = 'url'
client = requests.session()
# Retrieve the CSRF token first
csrf = client.get(url).cookies['csrftoken']

login_data = dict(username=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD, csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrf, next='/')
r = client.post(URL, data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=url))

# Check if it worked?
print r.status_code
```

Perhaps its bugged at your install?

**EDIT1:**

try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

client = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'url'

soup = BeautifulSoup(client.get(url).text, "html.parser")
csrf = soup.find(name="csrf")
```

Comment: i'm getting the same error.As per my understanding i think that the error is caused just because i'm not giving the correct token name,everything else is fine

Comment: Then I'm out of options... so you have to wait for the cavalry to help you out. GL!

Comment: so now trying a workaround with  selenium coz i searched that it gives the browser instance. hope it works.....btw thanx for your efforts.

Comment: had tried to find by using soup earlier before posting but no luck.......anyways thnx again man.Appreciate your efforts...!